# How to cross-reference to sections in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

For my lecture slides in `beamer` I would like to establish a section-framenumber numbering scheme. For this purpose I reset frame counter in `\AtBeginSection` and redefine the `\insertframenumber` command to reflect the new numbering scheme:

```
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\thesection-\theframenumber}
\AtBeginSection{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}
```

This works pretty well. However, I have not succeeded in getting cross-references right in this respect, that is to refer to some labeled `\frame[label=interesting]` as section-framenumber. Apparently, there is no way to, given the label, extract the section number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\thesection-\theframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[text line]{This is frame: \insertframenumber}
\AtBeginSection{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}{First Frame in Section One}
  Slide content\par
  \pause
  More content
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=interesting]{Second Frame in Section One -- The one to crossref to}
  Slide content
\end{frame}

\section{Two}
\begin{frame}{First Frame in Section Two}

  Now I want to crossref to interesting slide by section-framenumber (that is, somehow generate \textbf{1-2}) 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbackslash{}ref yields: \ref{interesting}, apparently that is the frame number
    \item \textbackslash{}page yields: \pageref{interesting}, apparently that is the PDF page number
    \item \textbackslash{}autoref yields: \autoref{interesting}, apparently that is the frame number again
    \item nothing there that yields \textbackslash{}thesection of our target label?
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I took a look at the generated `.aux`-file. I am not really good in deciphering `.aux`-files; however, as I read it, beamer does not even store there the section number (1 in this case) the label belongs to:

```
...
\newlabel{interesting<1>}{{2}{3}{One\relax }{Doc-Start}{}}
...
```

So am I out of luck here?

**Edit:** I am now considering looking into the `zref` package to solve my problem. The challenge will probably be to get it integrated with the `label=mylabel` frame option, which implicitly generates those helpful "overlay" labels (`mylabel<1>`, `mylabel<2>`, `...`) to refer to individual slides of a frame.

Any hints or ideas still are more than welcome :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `label` key of the `beamer` `frame` uses the `\label<>` macro internally. This uses the normal `\label` macro of LaTeX which uses the `\@currentlabel` macro for the label text. This macro is set by `\refstepcounter` which is used by sectioning macros, captions and also frames. It uses the content of the corresponding `\the...` macro, so setting `\theframenumber`, not `\insertframenumber` is important.

Note that `\insertframenumber` is by default set to `\@arabic\c@framenumber` which is the lower-level version of `\arabic{framenumber}`, i.e. the default definition of `\theframenumber`. So my first step was to redefine `\theframenumber` and make `\insertframenumber` use it:

```
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\thesection-\arabic{framenumber}}
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\theframenumber}
```

However, this doesn't work. After some debugging I found out that actually the `subsectionslide` counter is used for the `label` key. I have no idea why. Maybe the `\refstepcounter{subsectionslide}` is processed after the `\refstepcounter{framenumber}`. The related file is `beamerbaseframe.sty`.
It doesn't like it in the code, but I don't had time to follow all the conditionals in it.

Anyway, the solution is to also(?) set `\thesubsectionslide` to `\thesection-\arabic{framenumber}` or `\theframenumber`. Then the references are displayed as you want. However, references to the `subsectionslide` (whatever this is exactly) might be wrong.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\theframenumber}
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\thesection-\arabic{framenumber}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsectionslide}{\thesection-\arabic{framenumber}}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[text line]{This is frame: \insertframenumber}
\AtBeginSection{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\subsection{a}
\begin{frame}{First Frame in Section One}
  Slide content\par
  \pause
  More content
\end{frame}

\subsection{b}
\begin{frame}[label=interesting]{Second Frame in Section One -- The one to crossref to}
  Slide content
\end{frame}

\section{Two}
\begin{frame}{First Frame in Section Two}

  Now I want to crossref to interesting slide by section-framenumber (that is, somehow generate \textbf{1-2}) 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbackslash{}ref yields: \ref{interesting}, apparently that is the frame number
    \item \textbackslash{}page yields: \pageref{interesting}, apparently that is the PDF page number
    \item \textbackslash{}autoref yields: \autoref{interesting}, apparently that is the frame number again
    \item nothing there that yields \textbackslash{}thesection of our target label?
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin! I am on the jump so I cannot test your solution right now, but will do ASAP. The day before I also stumbled over the `\refstepcounter{subsectionslide}` issue, which (IMHO) makes no sense at all (should be `\stepcounter`): The framenumber returned by `\ref` is reset  with every subsection, but the number inserted by \insertframenumber is not, so cross-ref to frames by number stops working when one uses subsections. This bug has been [around for a while](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/118/sub-section-number-in-references-is-wrong), I've applied the patch.

Comment: The **combination** of Martin's answer (redefining `\theframenumber` and `\insertframenumber` and [this patch](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/118/sub-section-number-in-references-is-wrong) to `beamerbaseframe.sty`  works like a a charm. (@Martin : You might want to edit your answer in this respect.) The linked patch solves apparently a number of issues with respect to wrong reference counting by beamer, however, in my case it would also have been enough to change the first  `\refstepcounter{subsectionslide)` in `beamerbaseframe.sty` to `\stepcounter{subsectionslide}`.